# Get characters index in string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, include

I want to achieve something like this:

if array [ "a", "b", "c"] includes any of the characters of const word = "abracadabra" give me that character and its position in const word

I have tried something like this:

```js
const word = "abracadabra";
const input = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (let i = 0; i< word.length; i++) {
  if (input.includes(word(i))) {
  console.log(i + (word(i)));
  }
}
```

But that doesnt work, Can somebody help me with the logic and or syntax?
I am new to coding, thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: Do you know the difference between `word(i)` and `word[i]`?

Comment: " that doesn't work" is not what the computer says. It says "word is not a function", which makes it clear where the problem is - you're trying to use something that is not a function as a function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
for(let i=0;i<input.length;i++){
  if(word.indexOf(input[i]) != -1){
    console.log('word includes ',input[i])
  }
}
```

I think this will resolve your problem.

Comment: You do realize that this code is incorrect? The result does not match the description at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use brackets when accessing a field of an array. Parentheses are for calling functions.

```
const word = "abracadabra";
const input = ["a", "b", "c"];

for (let i = 0; i< word.length; i++) {
  if (input.includes(word[i])) {
      console.log(i + word[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question stated exactly:

> *give me that character and its position in const word*

use [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

```js
const word = "abracadabra";
const input = ["a", "b", "c"];

input.forEach(c => {
  const re = new RegExp(c, "g");
  let m;
  while (m = re.exec(word)) console.log(`${c} found at index ${m.index}`);
});
```

Another yet nice way to achieve the same is by using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const word = "abracadabra";
const input = ["a", "b", "c"];

const res = input.reduce((ob, c) => {
  ob[c] = [...word].reduce((a, w, i) => {
    if (w === c) a.push(i);
    return a;
  }, []);
  return ob;
}, {});


console.log(res);
```

which will return an Object, with the character property having an array with all the positions occurrences:

```js
{
  "a": [0, 3, 5, 7, 10],
  "b": [1, 8],
  "c": [4]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const word = "abracadabra";
const input = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (let i = 0; i< word.length; i++) {
  if (input.includes(word[i])) {
  console.log(i + (word[i]));
  }
}
```

please use the  square bracket **word[i]** not use this **word(i)**

Answer (score -1):

I think posting the question (formulating it) was enough to make me think of a better solution. I have a working snippet now:

```js
const word = "abracadabra";
const inPut = ["a", "b", "c"];
for (let i = 0; i< word.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j< (inPut.length); j++) {
        if (word.charAt(i).includes(inPut[j])) {
            console.log(i + (word.charAt(i)));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A much more verbose version, where all you had to do is index the string instead of trying to call it, i.e. replace `word(i)` by `word[i]`?